# Variable scope in aspx page

Tags: scope, webforms

Why is that the `scriptPath` variable is **out of scope** in the bottom of the code?

Shouldn't it be in scope throughout this page? In MVC, if I mark this on top of the page like

```
@{
    string scriptPath = "assets/scripts/",
           gkoConfig = "GkoConfig.js";
}
```

it is available throughout the current View. What am I missing now that I'm back to WebForms for a while?

[image]

If I change the code position, It get's weirder as inside the `<head>` I no longer have access to teh variable, but I do have, inside the `<body>` now... :-/

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you declare a variable in a Web Forms .aspx file, you’re actually declaring a local variable inside an auto-generated rendering method. ASP.NET generates separate rendering methods for all tags marked `runat="server"`, so you actually get a separate method for your head element. Now, the variable you declare can only exist in one of these methods - hence the 'weird' behavior.

You can see how this works if you [pre-compile your application using aspnet_compiler.exe.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) You will get compiled DLL files for each of your web forms pages; just open one of those up in Reflector to see the generated code. I wrote a minimal equivalent of your code with the variable declared outside the head tag, and here’s the top-level render method that I got:

```
private void __Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
{
    string str = "scripts/";
    __w.Write("\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\r\n\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n");
    parameterContainer.Controls[0].RenderControl(__w);
    __w.Write("\r\n<body>\r\n    ");
    parameterContainer.Controls[1].RenderControl(__w);
    __w.Write("\r\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"");
    __w.Write(str);
    __w.Write("jquery-1.4.1.min.js\"></script>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n");
}
```

You see that the variable that I declared (here named `str`) is scoped to this method, and it's calling other methods to render the head (and a form element marked `runat="server"`.)

A quick and dirty solution might be to simply remove the `runat="server"` from your head tag; however, I’d recommend that you declare a protected variable in your code-behind class for this. Adding a line like this to your code-behind file would work:

```
protected string scriptPath, gkoConfig;
```

You can then use these variables anywhere in your Web Forms code.

Comment: when you say "code-behind class", what do you mean (say, for a page like Index.aspx) ?

Comment: The code-behind class is the class declared in the .cs file for the page, for example, index.aspx.cs for index.aspx.

Comment: ok, understood. I started learning MVC directly whitout having "classic" ASP experience this why i didn't understand initially.. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could also declare your constants like this:

```
<script runat="server">
    private const string scriptPath = "assets/scripts/";
    private const string gkoConfig = "GkoConfig.js";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the head of the ASPX page gets processed separately from the body.

This problem is easily solved - all you need to do is use a class field in the code-behind with the access level set to protected.