# Access a databound variable in regular inline expression

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to access a databound variable within a regular C# inline expression.

I was hoping there was some way I could access it using the `Eval()` command, but you cannot use it inside a regular inline code block. (What I mean by that, is the `<% %>` tag).

**NOTE**: The below inline code is not complete, I set the boolean (IsCommented) beforehand.

```
<%
    if (IsCommented)
        Response.Write("<a href='#' onclick='Comment(" + Eval("commentid") + "', $(this)); return false;' class='btn btn-info'>Comment</a>");
    else
        Response.Write("<a href='#' onclick='Comment(" + Eval("commentid") + "', $(this)); return false;' class='btn btn-inverse'>Commented!</a>");
%>
```

Is this at all possible?

(Note that I have this all contained within a `ListView`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not getting your question properly,

But are you looking for something like this or will this solve your problem

```
<%if (IsCommented) {%>
        <a href='#' onclick='Comment('<%#Eval("commentid")%>', $(this)); return false;' class='btn btn-info'>Comment</a>;
    <%}else{%>
        <a href='#' onclick='Comment('<%#Eval("commentid")%>', $(this)); return false;' class='btn btn-inverse'>Commented!</a>";
<%}%>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot, though I ended up rehashing to program to solve the problem differently. Could you explain the lifetime of variables within inline expressions and their scope? Before seeing this, I had assumed that if I declared a variable within <% %> once outside the tag, the variable would be inaccessible to me, though apparently this is not the case.

Comment: Glad I could help! This post can help you understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872712/variables-scope-in-aspx-page